# Printing out the least occurring elements in an array

Tags: java, arrays

OK, so I found this question from a few days ago but it's on hold and it won't let me post anything on it.

***Note: The values or order in the array are completely random. They should also be able to be negative.

Someone recommended this code and was thumbed up for it, but I don't see how this can solve the problem. If one of the least occurring elements isn't at the BEGINNING of the array then this does not work. This is because the maxCount will be equal to array.length and the results array will ALWAYS take the first element in the code written below.

What ways are there to combat this, using simple java such as below? No hash-maps and whatnot. I've been thinking about it for a while but can't really come up with anything. Maybe using a double array to store the count of a certain number? How would you solve this? Any guidance?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 4 };
    int count = 0;
    int maxCount = 10;
    int[] results = new int[array.length];
    int k = 0; // To keep index in 'results'

    // Initializing 'results', so when printing, elements that -1 are not part of the result
    // If your array also contains negative numbers, change '-1' to another more appropriate
    for (int i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        results[i] = -1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (array[j] == array[i]) {
                count++;
            }
        }

        if (count <= maxCount) { // <= so it admits number with the SAME number of occurrences
            maxCount = count;
            results[k++] = array[i]; // Add to 'results' and increase counter 'k'
        }
        count = 0; // Reset 'count'
    }

    // Printing result
    for (int i : results) {
        if (i != -1) {
            System.out.println("Element: " + i + ", Number of occurences: " + maxCount);
        }
    }
}
```

credit to: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2670792/christian
for the code

I can't thumbs up so I'd just like to say here THANKS EVERYONE WHO ANSWERED.

Comment: I think most of us would consider a `HashMap` to be 'simple java'. So your question is more or less how to find least occurring elements with just arrays?

Comment: Moreover, this is a canonical use case for a multiset.

Comment: Yes MagicMan, that's my question

Comment: A `HashMap` is backed by an array. So the best way to do this without `HashMap`, I suppose, would be to copy the source code for `HashMap` and rename it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This algorithm is recording the values having the least number of occurrences *so far* (as it's processing) and then printing all of them alongside the value of `maxCount` (which is the count for the value having the *overall* smallest number of occurrences).

A quick fix is to record the count for each position and then only print those whose count is equal to the `maxCount` (which I've renamed `minCount`):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = { 5, 1, 2, 2, -1, 1, 5, 4 };
    int[] results = new int[array.length];
    int minCount = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (array[j] == array[i]) {
                results[i]++;
            }
        }
        if (results[i] <= minCount) {
            minCount = results[i];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        if (results[i] == minCount) {
            System.out.println("Element: " + i + ", Number of occurences: "
                    + minCount);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Element: 4, Number of occurences: 1
Element: 7, Number of occurences: 1
```

This version is also quite a bit cleaner and removes a bunch of unnecessary variables.

Comment: I like the way you think. That makes much more sense. Is there anyway to change it so that it can work for any integer, including -1?
actually, now that I think of it, minCount can never be -1, so theres no point in that condition, is there?

Comment: I'm right about that though, right? The previous code worked because you're counting the number of occurrences which can never be -1.

Comment: No. The previous code was using -1 as a special value to indicate that that position never contained the least number of occurrences.

Comment: I mean because you had the condition results[i] != -1 && results[i] == minCount. The first condition wasn't necessary

Comment: That's right. I originally just overlooked removing it once it was no longer needed. I've fixed that since. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use an oriented object approach.

First create a class `Pair` :

```
class Pair {
    int val;
    int occ;

    public Pair(int val){
        this.val = val;
        this.occ = 1;
    }

    public void increaseOcc(){
        occ++;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return this.val+"-"+this.occ;
    }
}
```

Now here's the main:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    int[] array = { 1,1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 6, 4, 4, 4 ,0};
    Arrays.sort(array);

    int currentMin = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int index = 0;
    Pair[] minOcc = new Pair[array.length];
    minOcc[index] = new Pair(array[0]);

    for(int i = 1; i < array.length; i++){
        if(array[i-1] == array[i]){
            minOcc[index].increaseOcc();
        } else {
            currentMin = currentMin > minOcc[index].occ ? minOcc[index].occ : currentMin;
            minOcc[++index] = new Pair(array[i]);
        }
    }

    for(Pair p : minOcc){
        if(p != null && p.occ == currentMin){
            System.out.println(p);
        }
    }

}
```

Which outputs:

```
0-1
6-1
```

**Explanation:**

First you sort the array of values. Now you iterate through it.

While the current value is equals to the previous, you increment the number of occurences for this value. Otherwise it means that the current value is different. So in this case you create a new Pair with the new value and one occurence.

During the iteration you will keep track of the minimum number of occurences you seen.

Now you can iterate through your array of Pair and check if for each Pair, it's occurence value is equals to the minimum number of occurences you found.

This algorithm runs in `O(nlogn)` (due to `Arrays.sort`) instead of `O(n²)` for your previous version.

Comment: +1 for a good solution. I assumed the constraint that I couldn't use `sort`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not as elegant as Iwburks answer, but I was just playing around with a 2D array and came up with this:

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
      int[] array = { 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, -4, 4, 5, 4 };
      int count = 0;
      int maxCount = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
      int[][] results = new int[array.length][];
      int k = 0; // To keep index in 'results'

      for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
                if (array[j] == array[i]) {
                     count++;
                }
           }
           if (count <= maxCount) { 
                maxCount = count;
                results[k++] = new int[]{array[i], count};
           }
           count = 0; // Reset 'count'
      }
      // Printing result
      for (int h = 0; h < results.length; h++) {
      if (results[h] != null && results[h][1] == maxCount ) {
          System.out.println("Element: " + results[h][0] + ", Number of occurences: " + maxCount);
      }
 }
```

Prints

```
Element: -4, Number of occurences: 1
Element: 5, Number of occurences: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example above, it looks like you are only using ints.  I would suggest the following solution in that situation.  This will find the last number in the array with the least occurrences.  I assume you don't want an object-oriented approach either.

```
int [] array = { 5, 1, 2, 40, 2, -1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 2, 40, 2, 1, 4 };

//initialize this array to store each number and a count after it so it must be at least twice the size of the original array
int [] countArray = new int [array.length * 2];

//this placeholder is used to check off integers that have been counted already
int placeholder = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

int countArrayIndex = -2;

for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    int currentNum = array[i];

    //do not process placeholders
    if(currentNum == placeholder){
        continue;
    }

    countArrayIndex = countArrayIndex + 2;

    countArray[countArrayIndex] = currentNum;
    int count = 1; //we know there is at least one occurence of this number

    //loop through each preceding number
    for(int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++)
    {
        if(currentNum == array[j])
        {
            count = count + 1;
            //we want to make sure this number will not be counted again
            array[j] = placeholder;  
        }
    }

    countArray[countArrayIndex + 1] = count;  

}     

//In the code below, we loop through inspecting each number and it's respected count to determine which one occurred least
//We choose Integer.MAX_VALUE because it's a number that easily indicates an error
//We did not choose -1 or 0 because these could be actual numbers in the array
int minNumber = Integer.MAX_VALUE; //actual number that occurred minimum amount of times
int minCount = Integer.MAX_VALUE; //actual amount of times the number occurred

for(int i = 0; i <= countArrayIndex; i = i + 2)
{

    if(countArray[i+1] <= minCount){
        minNumber = countArray[i];
        minCount = countArray[i+1];
    }
}

System.out.println("The number that occurred least was " + minNumber + ". It occured only " + minCount + " time(s).");
```